# Reason for lateral contraction when tensile stress is applied to string

Tags: elasticity

I have read that a wire contracts side ways on stretching it . But why? What happens at the atomic level when a string is stretched? When there is no force applied in the side ways direction, why does the wire contract sideways decreasing its cross section?

Comment: This is called the [Poisson Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson's_ratio). I don't have time to write up a full answer right now, but there's something you can start reading until somebody can put something here.

Answer (score 2):

Solids area basically incompressible, their volume is almost completely invariant to pressure:

$$\frac{\Delta V}{\Delta p} \approx 0$$

This means that when we stretch something with length $L_0$ and cross-section $A_0$, then:

$$L_0A_0=LA$$

Where $L$ and $A$ are the length and cross-section values after stretching, so we get:

$$A=\frac{L_0}{L}A_0$$

With $L>L_0$, then $A<A_0$, so the **cross-section reduces** to meet the incompressibility condition, on stretching.